# Codeigniter pagination - Array variable get empty on page 2

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, pagination

I'm working on search page, in that the search is based on an array `$s_id`. Once I search with some input value, the search result is showing perfectly along with the pagination link.(**pagination link is also perfect. . If I have 6 results and per_page is 2 so its showing 3 page link**).

Now my problem is once I click on page 2 its showing empty page, and I try to print `$s_id` on page 2 then the array is displaying like `Array ( [0] => )` that means on page 2 `$s_id` has some other value.

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function index()
        {        
        $s_id = array();
        $skills = $this->input->post('skills');
        //pagination settings
        $config['per_page'] = 2;
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('search');
        $config['first_url'] = site_url('search/').'1';
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['num_links'] = 3;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li><span><b>";
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = "</b></span></li>";
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination pagination-large">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>'; 
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a>';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

        $page = $this->uri->segment(2);

        $limit_end = ($page * $config['per_page']) - $config['per_page'];
        if ($limit_end < 0){
            $limit_end = 0;
        }

        if($skills == TRUE || $this->uri->segment(2) == TRUE){
            $s_id = explode(',', $skills[0]);
            if($s_id){
              $filter_session_data['skill_id_selected'] = $s_id;
            }else{
              $s_id = $this->session->userdata('skill_id_selected');
            }
            $data['skill_id_selected'] = $s_id;
            if(isset($filter_session_data)){
                $this->session->set_userdata($filter_session_data);
            }

            // print_r($s_id); exit();                     //commented
            // $s_id = array('2D Design','3D Design');     //commented

            $data['count_user'] =  $this->m_results->count_users($s_id);
            $config['total_rows'] = $data['count_user'];
            $data['freelancers'] = $this->m_results->search_people($s_id,$config['per_page'],$limit_end);
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $this->load->view('include/header');
            $this->load->view('search',$data);
            $this->load->view('include/footer');
        }else{  
            $this->load->view('include/header');
            $this->load->view('search');
            $this->load->view('include/footer');
        }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public function search_people($s_id,$limit_start,$limit_end)
{

    $this->db->from('search_result');
    if($s_id){
        $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$s_id[0]', skills) != ", 0);
        for($x=1; $x < count($s_id); $x++) {
            $this->db->or_where("FIND_IN_SET('$s_id[$x]', skills) != ", 0);
        } 
    }

    $this->db->limit($limit_start, $limit_end);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}


public function count_users($s_id=null)
{

    if($s_id){
        $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$s_id[0]', skills) != ", 0);
        for($x=1; $x < count($s_id); $x++) {
            $this->db->or_where("FIND_IN_SET('$s_id[$x]', skills) != ", 0);
        } 
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Give a sample url(what you are seeing in the browser) for the search result of first page and second page

Comment: first-page: `http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/search`.                            second-page:`http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/search/2`.                                  I think the URL all fine.

Comment: URL looks fine. But `$skills = $this->input->post('skills');` - is matter on page number 2. Look into the below my answer

Answer (score 0):

`$skills = $this->input->post('skills');` - is matter. You will get this value when you submit a form using post method. for `next page` you have to submit the form with `skills` and page number input not simply redirect the url.

Or

Change the form submission method as `GET`. So you can easy redirect the url with search field value easy for next and previous pages.

Comment: If i add one more input field(**not an array input**) and do the same steps its working perfeclty for all the pages.

Comment: and also I'm using session userdata. But I think its not effecting on that array.

Comment: one more input field is `skills` right? then it should be fine.

Comment: No no.. for keyword (**a search string**).

Comment: Basically I have 3 input fields (**keyword,skills,location**). In these keyword and location are working fine but not skills, that why I post the question here . **NB:** I just skip the code for keyword and location search from the whole code that I post over here.